# Class Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistryStorage does not exist

Tags: magento2, m2e, m2epro

Installed a module on Magento 2 website, after running a **setup:upgrade, reindex and cache**. Then I run a `setup:di:compile`, but I received an error.

> Class Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistryStorage does not
>   exist

**I have done a chmod 777 var**

Also tried

```
rm -Rf ../var/cache/
rm -Rf ../var/page_cache/
rm -Rf ../var/generation/
rm -Rf ../var/di/
```

Any ideas how I can solve the issue?  I am using Magento ver. 2.0.13

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please run below command

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                // 644 permission for files
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                // 755 permission for directory 
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;            // 777 permission for var folder    
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static var/composer_home
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
chmod -Rf 777 pub/ var/
```